# gulp 4 async await

Tags: npm, gulp

Can you help me. I am trying to create a gulp task where after building my code it will try to save everything to sharepoint. I added await to my promise to make it wait to finish first before proceeding but its not waiting and try to save files in my build eve its not finish yet.

```
gulp.task('build', async function() {
  //BUILD FILES
  await new Promise(resolve => {
    run('npm run build')
      .exec()
      .pipe(gulp.dest('output/run'));
    resolve();
  });
  //AFTER BUILD IT WILL TRY TO SAVE Build folder files to sharepoint
  gulp.src(['./build/**']).pipe(
    spsave(
      {
        siteUrl: siteUrl,
        folder: folderUrl,
        flatten: false
      },
      cred.account
    )
  );
  notify('Process Done 2!');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure it out. I added an on at the end of my pipe and that where I call my resolve

```
gulp.task('build', async function() {
  await new Promise(resolve => {
    run('npm run build')
      .exec()
      .pipe(gulp.dest('output/run'))
      .on('end', resolve);
  });
  gulp.src(['./build/**']).pipe(
    spsave(
      {
        siteUrl: siteUrl,
        folder: folderUrl,
        flatten: false
      },
      cred.account
    )
  );
  notify('Process Done 2!');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite part of your code to this:

```
await new Promise(resolve => {
    run('npm run build')
      .exec()
      .pipe(gulp.dest('output/run'));
      .on('end', resolve);
  });
```

Means you wait on event `end` from pipe and then resolve promise.